# How to create a dynamic date format?

Tags: 7

I'm fairly new to Drupal and I'm struggling to find where and how I should approach the problem I'm describing below. I suspect I will have to dive in the code but that's ok I'm comfortable with PHP.

I have a content type "Event" with a "Date & Time" field called "Event Start Date". I've configured the Date format to be "l, F d, Y - h:i a", but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

I need to add a condition to my date format so that it doesn't display :00 when the minutes are at 00.

For example

```
Tuesday, January 25, 2017 - 9:15 am
Tuesday, January 25, 2017 - 9:00 am
```

should display

```
Tuesday, January 25, 2017 - 9:15 am
Tuesday, January 25, 2017 - 9 am
```

How and where should I be doing this in code?

Preferably, I would like to be able to tell when to apply this rule.

Comment: where do you want to show it?

Comment: On the node page with the other details of the event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best solution is used custom field formatter for date type:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_info().
 */
function mymodule_field_formatter_info() {
  return array(
      'mymodule_custom_datestamp' => array(
          'label' => t('Custom datestamp formatter'),
          'field types' => array('datestamp'), 
      ),
      'mymodule_custom_date' => array(
          'label' => t('Custom date formatter'),
          'field types' => array('date', 'datetime'), 
      ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_view().
 */
function mymodule_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
  $element = array();

  switch ($display['type']) {
    case 'mymodule_custom_datestamp':
      foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
        $tmp = (integer)$item['value'];
        $minutes = (integer)date('i', $tmp);
        if(empty($minutes)){ //you'll update only values with :00
          $element[$delta] = array('#markup' => date('l, F d, Y - h a', $tmp));
        }else{
          $element[$delta] = array('#markup' => date('l, F d, Y - h:i a', $tmp));
        }
      }
      break;
    case 'mymodule_custom_date':
          .....
          break;
  }

  return $element;
}
```

You can use it anywhere and It uses the least resources.

Comment: This is the best answer.  If you also need this in views, you may want a views field plugin to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the theming of field:
create file into your theme for field "Event Start Date" 
field--field-event-start-date.tpl.php

or use function in template.php of your theme (for delete seconds)

```
 function mytheme_field__field_event_start_date($vars) {
    $value = (integer)$vars['element']['#items'][0]['value'];
    if(empty($value % 100)){ //you'll update only values with :00
       $vars['items'][0]['#markup'] = date('l, F d, Y - h a', $value);
    }

 }
```

for delete minutes:

```
function mytheme_field__field_event_start_date($vars) {
  global $language;
  $tmp_date = $vars['items'][0]['#markup'];

  switch ($language->language) {
    case 'fr':
      $vars['items'][0]['#markup'] = str_replace('h&nbsp;00', 'h', $tmp_date);
      break;

    default:
      $vars['items'][0]['#markup'] = str_replace(':00', '', $tmp_date);
      break;
  }
}
```

P.S. I could be wrong with variable names

Comment: What does the index [0] represent? Is it possible to have move value?

Comment: @EricB. I'm using a raw value. index [0] for simple value, if multi values need to use foreach. But I had mistake. I was thinking you want to delete seconds, and your solution works no right for that situation. Before, I was wanted to offer it (used function replace).... OK.  BUT you should use the theming of field: my variant executes only when render the field, in your variant - when render any fields. It is more  time on the render of page. Into function you're using your solution.

Comment: @EricB. I added the changes

Comment: Thanks Alex, I'm looking for a more broad approach. With the hook I can target all "datestamp" field not just the one for the "Event" content type.  Anyway I'm still facing an issue with Views and Search API, they don't seem to trigger the hook_field_attach_preprocess_alter/

Comment: Ideally the Date Format should accept a callback function instead of only providing support for PHP format, this would solve a lot of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I implemented using the hook_field_attach_preprocess_alter hook.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_attach_preprocess_alter
 */
function mymodule_field_attach_preprocess_alter(&$variables, $context) {  
  global $language;

  foreach ($variables['content'] as $field_name => $field) {

    // remove minutes formating if at 00 on field type datestamp.
    if (isset($field['#field_type']) && $field['#field_type'] === 'datestamp') {
      $tmp_date = $variables['content'][$field_name][0]['#markup'];

      switch ($language->language) {
        case 'en':
          $variables['content'][$field_name][0]['#markup'] = str_replace(':00', '', $tmp_date);
          break;

        case 'fr':
          $variables['content'][$field_name][0]['#markup'] = str_replace('h&nbsp;00', 'h', $tmp_date);
          break;

        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```